# Getting communication Link failure while connecting to Aurora-Mysql after cluster failover

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-aurora

My java application is working fine and inserting data into Aurora-Mysql before failover after failover it gives error "Communication link failure".Ours is 2 node cluster of Aurora-Mysql.

Below is the error:
ould not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:

```
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542)

    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:430)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.save(Unknown Source)

    at com.wu.oneplatform.controller.OrderControllerImpl.saveOrderDetail(OrderControllerImpl.java:81)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at com.wu.oneplatform.utils.tracing.JaegerFilter.doFilter(JaegerFilter.java:21)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at com.wu.oneplatform.utils.logging.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:30)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)

    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)

    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)

    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:

```
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:72)

    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:238)

    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)

    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:500)

    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

```
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2074)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)

    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)

    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

```
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor121.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)

    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:1259)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:575)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)

    ... 93 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 86 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 86 milliseconds ago.

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)

    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:555)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:725)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:664)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:979)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:914)

    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1150)

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:801)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.commit(Unknown Source)

    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:80)

    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232)

    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)

    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)

    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)

    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

```
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)

    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:549)
```

.
Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your issue fully, but it looks like your app was running fine, and then when the cluster had a failover, your app stopped working with a bunch of errors.

The stack traces that you have shared indicate that the app has detected connection closure, but is continuing to use the stale connections to open new transactions. Do you have logic to gracefully re-open connections if they end up getting closed? That is a common paradigm when interacting with databases that work with persisted connections.